# Heroku node app not starting

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have created a very basic nodejs app which works locally. when i am pushing it to my heroku server, app is getting crashed with following error in log

```
var express = require("express");

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT||3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get('/',function(req,res){res.status(200).send('Hello World')});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(400).send(err.message);
});

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Slack bot listening on port ' + port);
});
```

> ```
> 2016-01-05T19:39:14.346745+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>
> command `npm start` 2016-01-05T19:39:16.207970+00:00 app[web.1]: npm
>
> ERR! Linux 3.13.0-71-generic 2016-01-05T19:39:16.209056+00:00
>
> app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12 2016-01-05T19:39:16.210546+00:00
>
> app[web.1]: npm ERR!  2016-01-05T19:39:16.210779+00:00 app[web.1]: npm
> ```
>
> ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

package.json

```
{
  "name": "slackbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Slack Hello World Bot",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/fffff/SlackBot.git"
  },
  "author": "Jasim Aboobacker",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/fffff/SlackBot/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/fffff/SlackBot#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.14.2",
    "express": "^4.13.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is you `npm start` command entry in `package.json`?

Comment: @usandfriends have added my package.json

Comment: Do you have a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-a-procfile)?

Comment: @usandfriends No.. this project structure was created manually...Now i created a new nodejs project using heroku 'create' and it is working on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these steps one by one and it should work nicely.
Download and install node and npm from websites.

*[link node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)*

*[link npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/download)*

rest of the commands are as below

```
sudo -i
```

Put root password if asked.

Now go to the project folder of your choice through cmd/terminal

```
 npm install -g express
 npm install -g express-generator
 express
 cd . && npm install
 SET DEBUG=<*folder name*>:* & npm start
```

Now in the folder type the following command to set up git local directory.

```
 git init
 git add .
 git commit -m "initial commits"
```

Then create an account in Heroku and follow the following steps.

```
 heroku create <application_name>
 git push heroku master
```

nb:you may be asked to give username and password for your heroku account during the process ;so proceed accordingly.

Now type the following to add a single web dyno

```
 heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Then

```
 heroku open
```

Cheers!!